# How do you strip HTML from the node summary that appears on taxonomy node listing pages?

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I've tried using hook_preprocess_node() inside of a if statement for arg(0) == 'taxonomy', but changes to the node aren't carried through to display.

What is the best way to make the teasers appear in plain text (stripped HTML) when listing in the taxonomy node listing page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within `node--taxonomy.tpl.php`, you could isolate the field data for your teaser or any field, depending on how you have that template set up, and apply the php [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to that field data.

For example:

```
$teaser = render($content['body'][0]);
$textteaser = strip_tags($teaser);
```

This video is a great starting point for learning about the theming templates if that is new: [Theming Fields and Nodes with Templates](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxZQqgvJk3s)

---

One other idea is to isolate the div that wraps each teaser (if possible) and use jQuery to transform the content using the relevant CSS selector using `.text()` method.

Comment: I was really looking for the best place to find the teaser. Thanks.

Comment: I assumed you weren't supposed to put any logic in the tpl files, but I guess this is the only method here.

Comment: I'm sure there is another method. I wish I knew it, this is just the only way i would know how to go about it...